# Internet Explorer 9 console not available on F12 developer tools

Tags: internet-explorer-9, ie-developer-tools

I am stumped on what seems to be an easy thing.  I would like to view the console for testing purposes on IE 9 (version 9.0.8112.16421 and running on Windows 7, service pack 1) and do not see it on the 'F12 developer tools' menu.

I have Googled the above mentioned and have come across some threads that actually show a different set of tabs than what I see on the developer tools menu for IE 9.  The menu items I see are as follows.  File, Find, Disable, View, Images, Cache, Tools, Validate, Browser Mode.  As you can see, no reference to the Console or Script tabs.

Do I need to download a plugin?  Any information you can provide is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hit F12 and only see File, Find, Disable, View, Images, Cache, Tools, Validate, Browser Mode my guess is that the console is minimized. Try Ctrl + M or clicking on the restore window button located to the right of the Browser Mode display. Hope that gets you going.